# Handling meaningless changes with git

Tags: git

I have some config files which I would like to version as a part of a git repo, but the order of the fields in the config changes some times when I run the software. The order of the fields does not matter whatsoever to the software, so I would like for it to not matter for git either.

It would pollute my commit history if I were to commit these changes, and the files pollute my `git status` otherwise. The ideal option would be something like manual tracking of files.

How should i handle files that changes in meaningless ways?

Comment: You can't make git ignore these changes if you ask it to track the file. What you should do is only track a template of that file, and keep the actual file with the actual configuration out of the repository (ignored).

Comment: Why not try `git update-index --assume-unchanged <<config_file>>`?

Comment: Storing a template solves the opposite problem to the one stated, and `assume-unchanged` will cause problems whenever you have a change you *do* want to share (which must be sometimes if you want to track the file).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen The problem with a template is that it requires manual set-up each time the repository is fetched, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: @houtanb, as Mark says, `assume-unchanged` would require `no-assume-unchanged` to be run each time the file should be committed. And it requires manual setup for each clone of the repo.

Comment: @totokaka maybe you should just store the config file in config.example and in `.gitignore` simply ignore the file called `config`. That way each person has an example of how the config file should be set up but the file in the repository won't change....

Comment: @houtanb This is my backup-plan, but as I pointed out to Lasse, this requires manual set-up each time the repository is cloned.

Answer (score 3):

There's not a good *general* solution to this problem.  `git` wants to use hashes to determine "same"-ness and a re-ordering of the properties will always change the hash.

What I suppose you could do, if the order in the file truly doesn't matter, is to use a filter to sort it when adding it to the index.  This assumes that the order of the entire file is irrelevant, which may or may not suit your file format.

First you would create a .gitattributes file in your project root, with an entry like

```
path/to/config/file filter=sorted
```

You can use wildcards (with same meaning as in .gitignore), but one way or other you want to associate the filter with each of your config files where order doesn't matter.  This should be `add`ed and `commit`ed.

Then you have to create the filter config, so you issue the command

```
git config filter.sorted.clean sort
```

Now, no matter what order the lines appear in your work tree, they will be in a single (sorted) order in the index (and when committed).  (Of course that also means a fresh checkout of the file - such as after a clone - will have the file in sorted order.)

Again this only works for file formats that can be safely sorted - such as a key/value properties file that doesn't have comments on separate lines.  But "order doesn't matter" could mean other things.  Like maybe you have XML files wherein the order of top-level elements doesn't matter, but each such element spans multiple lines and must be kept together.  Or something else entirely...

In those cases, you would need a tool that can accept the file content on STDIN, normalize the representation in a way that eliminates "unimportant" differences, and print the result on STDOUT.  You would use that as your `clean` filter instead of `sort`.

Comment: I think this is a good solution. Unfortunately the format in question is yaml, so the line ordering caries some meaning. I am sure I can find a way to sort the keys of the file.